# Efficient way to convert a dictionary into another dictionary where all the keys are modified?

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

In Swift, I have this type of dictionary:

```swift
let typingAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
]
```

I need to convert it into another dictionary where the key is the `rawValue`. So something like this:

```swift
[
    NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.red,
]
```

One way I know I can achieve this is by creating a new dictionary, then enumerating all the keys of the original dictionary and setting the values in this new dictionary.

However, is there a better way similar to how Arrays have things like map, reduce etc?

Comment: I can only think of `reduce(into:_:)` with `let output = typingAttributes.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { $0[$1.key.rawValue] = $1.value }`

Comment: @Larme thanks, that worked. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Whydoyouhatespaces?Itmakesitreallyhardtoread.

Comment: @Alexander Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation Prior to [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77663491/revisions), these code snippets were all in one line, without any spaces. Almost all their content was hidden off the right edge, and it was pretty much unreadable. Give your code some space to make it legible :)

Comment: @Alexander ah, I got it. Thank you and I am sorry my fault. Will take care of it next time.

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation No worries. It'll help with your code's readability, not just for StackOverflow questions, but more generally. I'd suggest following a style guide (e.g. [Google's](https://google.github.io/swift/)), which has good rules-of-thumb for improving readability more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use `reduce(into:_:)`:

```
let output = typingAttributes.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { partialResult, tuple in
    let newKey = //Get new key from tuple.key
    partialResult[newKey] = tuple.value
}
```

In your case, since you are using `NSAttributedString.Key` for the dictionary keys, and you want the raw string value:

```
let newKey = tuple.key.rawValue
```

Which can then be simplified into:

```
let output = typingAttributes.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { 
    $0[$1.key.rawValue] = $1.value
}
```

With an extension:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func mapKeys<T>(_ key: (Key) -> T) -> [T: Value] {
        reduce(into: [T: Value]()) {
            let newKey = key($1.key)
            $0[newKey] = $1.value
        }
    }
}
```

Usages:

```
let output = typingAttributes.mapKeys { $0.rawValue }
```

Other samples uses:

```
//Convert the keys into their int value (it'd crash if it's not an int)
let testInt = ["1": "a", "2": "b"].mapKeys { Int($0)! }
print(testInt)


//Keep only the first character of the keys
let testPrefix = ["123": "a", "234": "b"].mapKeys { String($0.prefix(1)) }
print(testPrefix)

//Fixing keys into our owns, more "readable" and "Swift friendly for instance
let keysToUpdate = ["lat": "latitude", "long": "longitude", "full_name": "fullName"]
let testFixKeys = ["lat": 0.4, "long": 0.5, "full_name": "Seed", "name": "John", "age": 34].mapKeys { keysToUpdate[$0] ?? $0 }
print(testFixKeys)

//etc.
```